# SQL Server bcp parameter, native, character, Unicode native, Unicode character, when to use each?

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I'm reading [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191516.aspx) that describing the bcp utility. It states that:

> This section contains the following examples that show how to use bcp
> commands to create a non-XML format file:
>
> ```
> A. Creating a non-XML format file for native data
>
> B. Creating a non-XML format file for character data
>
> C. Creating a non-XML format file for Unicode native data
>
> D. Creating a non-XML format file for Unicode character data
> ```
>
> The examples use the HumanResources.Department table in the
> AdventureWorks2012 sample database. The HumanResources.Department
> table contains four columns: DepartmentID, Name, GroupName, and
> ModifiedDate.

I'm not clear what does these types mean? When to use each?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two dimensions:

- native vs. character. Native format creates a binary file. Character format creates a text file. Use character when you want the result to be human readable and usable for other apps (eg. import in Excel). Use native if both the source and destinations are SQL Server and human readability is not desired/needed.
- Unicode vs. non-Unicode. Unicode will store strings in wide format (Unicode encoding). non-Unicode will store them in the specified code page encoding (the `-C` argument). If space is not a concern, use Unicode, unless you enjoy pain.

You have to realize that you're seeing a product with +20 years history behind, there is [path dependence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_dependence). Nowadays I always use native Unicode (-n -w) unless I have *specific* reasons not to.

Answer (score 0):

I was needing more information as to the differences between Unicode and non-Unicode.

https://irfansworld.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/what-is-unicode-and-non-unicode-data-formats/

If and when the above link becomes unavailable the information contained in that link is also contained below:

**Unicode :**
A Unicode character takes more bytes to store the data in the database. As we all know, many global industries wants to increase their business worldwide and grow at the same time, they would want to widen their business by providing services to the customers worldwide by supporting different languages like Chinese, Japanese, Korean and Arabic. Many websites these days are supporting international languages to do their business and to attract more and more customers and that makes life easier for both the parties.

To store the customer data into the database the database must support a mechanism to store the international characters, storing these characters is not easy, and many database vendors have to revised their strategies and come up with new mechanisms to support or to store these international characters in the database. Some of the big vendors like Oracle, Microsoft, IBM and other database vendors started providing the international character support so that the data can be stored and retrieved accordingly to avoid any hiccups while doing business with the international customers.

The difference in storing character data between Unicode and non-Unicode depends on whether non-Unicode data is stored by using double-byte character sets. All non-East Asian languages and the Thai language store non-Unicode characters in single bytes. Therefore, storing these languages as Unicode uses two times the space that is used specifying a non-Unicode code page. On the other hand, the non-Unicode code pages of many other Asian languages specify character storage in double-byte character sets (DBCS). Therefore, for these languages, there is almost no difference in storage between non-Unicode and Unicode.

**Encoding Formats:**
Some of the common encoding formats for Unicode are UCS-2, UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 have been made available by database vendors to their customers. For SQL Server 7.0 and higher versions Microsoft uses the encoding format UCS-2 to store the UTF-8 data. Under this mechanism, all Unicode characters are stored by using 2 bytes.

Unicode data can be encoded in many different ways. UCS-2 and UTF-8 are two common ways to store bit patterns that represent Unicode characters. Microsoft Windows NT, SQL Server, Java, COM, and the SQL Server ODBC driver and OLEDB provider all internally represent Unicode data as UCS-2.

The options for using SQL Server 7.0 or SQL Server 2000 as a backend server for an application that sends and receives Unicode data that is encoded as UTF-8 include:

For example, if your business is using a website supporting ASP pages, then this is what happens:

If your application uses Active Server Pages (ASP) and you are using Internet Information Server (IIS) 5.0 and Microsoft Windows 2000, you can add "<% Session.Codepage=65001 %>" to your server-side ASP script. This instructs IIS to convert all dynamically generated strings (example: Response.Write) from UCS-2 to UTF-8 automatically before sending them to the client.

If you do not want to enable sessions, you can alternatively use the server-side directive "<%@ CodePage=65001 %>".

Any UTF-8 data sent from the client to the server via GET or POST is also converted to UCS-2 automatically. The Session.Codepage property is the recommended method to handle UTF-8 data within a web application. This Codepage setting is not available on IIS 4.0 and Windows NT 4.0.

**Sorting and other operations :**

The effect of Unicode data on performance is complicated by a variety of factors that include the following:

1. The difference between Unicode sorting rules and non-Unicode sorting rules
2. The difference between sorting double-byte and single-byte characters
3. Code page conversion between client and server

Performing operations like >, <, ORDER BY are resource intensive and will be difficult to get correct results if the codepage conversion between client and server is not available.

Sorting lots of Unicode data can be slower than non-Unicode data, because the data is stored in double bytes. On the other hand, sorting Asian characters in Unicode is faster than sorting Asian DBCS data in a specific code page, because DBCS data is actually a mixture of single-byte and double-byte widths, while Unicode characters are fixed-width.

**Non-Unicode :**

Non Unicode is exactly opposite to Unicode. Using non Unicode it is easy to store languages like ‘English’ but not other Asian languages that need more bits to store correctly otherwise truncation will occur.

Now, let’s see some of the advantages of not storing the data in Unicode format:

1. It takes less space to store the data in the database hence we will save lot of hard disk space.
2. Moving of database files from one server to other takes less time.
3. Backup and restore of the database makes huge impact and it is good for DBA’s that it takes less time

**Non-Unicode vs. Unicode Data Types: Comparison Chart**

The primary difference between unicode and non-Unicode data types is the ability of Unicode to easily handle the storage of foreign language characters which also requires more storage space.

| Non-Unicode | Unicode |
| --- | --- |
| (char, varchar, text) | (nchar, nvarchar, ntext) |
| Stores data in fixed or variable length | Same as non-Unicode |
| char: data is padded with blanks to fill the field size. For example, if a char(10) field contains 5 characters the system will pad it with 5 blanks | nchar: same as char |
| varchar: stores actual value and does not pad with blanks | nvarchar: same as varchar |
| requires 1 byte of storage | requires 2 bytes of storage |
| char and varchar: can store up to 8000 characters | nchar and nvarchar: can store up to 4000 characters |
| Best suited for US English: One problem with data types that use 1 byte to encode each character is that the data type can only represent 256 different characters. This forces multiple encoding specifications (or code pages) for different alphabets such as European alphabets, which are relatively small. It is also impossible to handle systems such as the Japanese Kanji or Korean Hangul alphabets that have thousands of characters. | Best suited for systems that need to support at least one foreign language: The Unicode specification defines a single encoding scheme for most characters widely used in businesses around the world. All computers consistently translate the bit patterns in Unicode data into characters using the single Unicode specification. This ensures that the same bit pattern is always converted to the same character on all computers. Data can be freely transferred from one database or computer to another without concern that the receiving system will translate the bit patterns into characters incorrectly. |